# Copy and Paste under specific Header

Tags: excel, vba, automation

[image: WIPTX Image that shows the headers]
I have 6 different headers under the WIPTX worksheet that will be pulling information from the TestData tab which is essentially data that will be uploaded from a SharePoint site. I want to be able to copy and paste rows that have specific values like the type of status or by name
under each header in the WIPTX worksheet. Headers are in columns A-C, E-G, I-K, M-O, Q-S, and U-W. Headers are of different status's that are in the TestData worksheet. Status include Assigned, Accepted, In Progress, On Hold, Completed, and Cancelled.
Will this be possible?
Code that I have so far works but it does not paste under specific header columns.

I have tried researching and looing at other sources but I am still not able to find the right code that is specific to what I am looking for.

```
Sub Update1()

Dim LastRow1 As Long, LastRow2 As Long, i As Long

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("TestData")
      LastRow1 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
      For i = 1 To LastRow1
          If .Range("A" & i).Value = "Thomas Xiong" Then
              LastRow2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("All Projects with NetBuilds").Cells(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("All Projects with NetBuilds").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
              .Rows(i).Copy ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("All Projects with NetBuilds").Rows(LastRow2 + 1)
          End If
      Next i
End With

End Sub
```

Is this possible?

Comment: If you are trying to copy and paste a row, you can't have different groups on the same row. You need to copy and paste specific columns for each header. Lets say Columns A-C from sheet TestData and paste them into the lastrow available on the header needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should help you:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Update1()

    Dim wsData As Worksheet, wsProjects As Worksheet, LastRow As Long, Col As Integer, CopyRange As Range, C As Range

    With ThisWorkbook
        Set wsData = .Sheets("TestData") 'refering the worksheet with all the data
        Set wsProjects = .Sheets("All Projects with NetBuilds") 'refering the worksheet with the headers
    End With


    For Each C In wsData.Range("A2", wsData.Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown)) 'Lets assume the criteria is on the column A
        With wsData
            Select Case C.Value
                Case "Assigned"
                    With wsData
                        Set CopyRange = .Range(.Cells(C.Row, 3), .Cells(C.Row, 5)) 'Here I'm assuming you want to copy data from Columns B To D
                    End With
                Case "Accepted"
                    With wsData
                        Set CopyRange = .Range(.Cells(C.Row, 7), .Cells(C.Row, 9)) 'Here I'm assuming you want to copy data from Columns G To I
                    End With

            '... all your headers
            End Select
        End With
        With wsProjects
            Col = .Cells.Find(C).Column 'Find the header column
            LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, Col).End(xlUp).Row + 1 'find the last row on that header
            CopyRange.Copy .Cells(LastRow, Col) 'paste the range (this method will copy everything from the source)
        End With
    Next C

    'In case you are always copying the same range of cells skip the select case, delete the CopyRange variable and just copy paste on the last block

End Sub
```

Comment: I am receiving an error on Col=.Cells.Find(C).Column?

Comment: The above code was just an example. You must change it to suit your needs. C in my code is the cell on column A, so if the cell on column A ain't your headers it will throw an error.

Comment: Hey Damian, I am still having trouble with the above code. I have added all my headers to the case statement but I am now receiving an error: Expected function or variable?

Comment: In which column are contained all the headers? because i'm assuming the headers are in column A in the worksheet testdata

Comment: actually the headers are in worksheet WIPTX and I am trying to copy and paste the rows of different status's from worksheet TestData into the headers Assigned, Accepted, In Progress, On hold, Completed, and Canceled.

Comment: Well so, where are the status on  the testdata sheet? in which column?

Comment: For instance, in the TestData worksheet In column A there are the Names, in Column B there are the status's that state: Assigned, Accepted, In Progress, On hold, Completed, and Canceled. What I want to do is copy and paste the rows of the different status into the worksheet WIPTX under that specific status header. Wish I could add a picture.

Comment: Then you need to change: `wsData.Range("A2", wsData.Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown))` to `wsData.Range("B2", wsData.Cells(1, 2).End(xlDown))` because your status are on column B and i assumed they were on column A.

Comment: I have changed that but I am still receiving an error: Object variable or With Block variable not set. Run-time error 91 line Col = .Cells.Find(C).Column 'Find the header column

Comment: Sorry @TJunky I've forgot to add some `With`, my answer is edited and it should work now.

Comment: I am still receiving an error Object variable or With Block variable not set. Run-time error 91 line Col = .Cells.Find(C).Column 'Find the header column?

Comment: Can you give me your workbook with a limited sample of data and my macro implemented? you can change the data if it's trouble to share.

Comment: Sure do you have an email or is there a way I can link it to you? and would it be easier to use a if then statement? for instance: If .Column("B" & i).Value = "On Hold" Then
Copy and paste row under header On Hold in worksheet "WIPTX" in the next available line
Else
If .Column("B" & i).Value = "Completed" Then
Copy and paste row under header Completed in worksheet "WIPTX" in the next available line

Comment: `Select` looks easier to read than the If, you can use wetransfer to upload the workbook and paste the link back here.

Comment: [link](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/628716971cdc1fafbb4635fb24ed8b3620190409153313/34ab16 )  this should be the link

Comment: I just tried your workbook, added `If Not CopyRange Is Nothing Then` before the `CopyRange.Copy .Cells(LastRow, Col)` . Your code had `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("All Projects with NetBuilds")` while your actual workbook has a worksheet called `"WIPTX"` once I changed the name of the sheet for `wsProjects` everything run smooth. Also you changed `.Cells.Find(C)` for `.Cells.Find(A)` don't do that.

Comment: Thank you, the code runs but it doesn't paste anything into worksheet WIPTX?